# Deploy settings during 1st install Android App

Tags: android, deployment, sharedpreferences, settings

I'm developping an app that contains some settings like server ip, sharedpreference filename and other that I would prefer save into a single file and not hard coded somewhere in the code.

So I would like to know what are the best practices nowadays concerning the deployement of these kind of settings. More, how to access it everywhere in the app ?

The android  sharedpreference allows me to save it after the 1st launch but I don't know how to deploy it with the App.

regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to deploy arbitrary data is the use of [raw resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

Create a file with your settings and save it to the raw resource folder. When your app is run for the first time, you can create your SharedPreference instance and copy the values from the raw resource to the preferences.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a Configuration.java class and put the configuration there. You can have different build flavors for different build types (development, production etc.)

Another option would be to use the class generated by Gradle: BuildConfig.class, where you can put some configuration data from your build.gradle script.

EDIT:
Shared Preferences shouldn't be used for that if the server IP doesn't change during the lifetime of the application.